# C++11 future::wait_for compile error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

i am trying to make multi-threading application where every thread will be proccessing task for different time. So i want to use future and future::wait_for function. 
But when i use only code from [CPP reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/wait_for)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::future<int> future = std::async(std::launch::async, [](){ 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        return 8;  
    }); 

    std::cout << "waiting...\n";
    std::future_status status;
    do {
        status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        if (status == std::future_status::deferred) {
            std::cout << "deferred\n";
        } else if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
            std::cout << "timeout\n";
        } else if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
            std::cout << "ready!\n";
        }
    } while (status != std::future_status::ready); 

    std::cout << "result is " << future.get() << '\n';
}
```

I get compile error:

```
 thread.cpp:31:58: error: cannot convert ‘bool’ to ‘std::future_status’ in assignment
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 and gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
Any thoughts ? 
Thanks !

Comment: My first thought is that there's only 27 lines in that file yet your error is on line 31.

Comment: Really ? What about indent lines somewhere ? :)

Comment: Tomas, my point is that your error message is not that useful unless we can establish the line (and file for that matter). Either post the correct code or indicate the line in the question somehow. Otherwise you're likely to get less help since we've got better things to do than psychic debugging :-)

Comment: status = future.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

Comment: When i install g++4.8 everything is working fine ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

G++ 4.6.3 is not supporting C++11 fully, so updating to a later version that has full support for C++11 (which is gcc 4.7 or later) will solve this sort of issue. Or use clang 3.4 (3.2 supports a lot of C++11, but 3.4 supports a lot more and has better optimisation on top of that).

Comment: When you say "3.2 supports a _log_ of C++11", do you mean _lot_?

Comment: @Alex: Of course I do. Fingers and brain not working together, clearly.

Answer (score 3):

According to this commit log, the return type was changed from `bool` to `std::future_status` in Feb 2012 and GCC 4.7 (on Mar 22, 2012) was the first release shipped with the new version of `wait_for`.

- https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/commit/f7273180cc277a28a6779a21bfa5d5e878254c5f